# How do you set-up the HR Database that comes with SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm stuck on this part:

[image]

Previous to this I successfully unlocked the HR database like so:

```
ALTER USER hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

then

```
ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY oracle

CREATE USER Adel identified by oracle;

grant connect, resource to Adel;
```

Answer (score 1):

Select "SID" instead of "Service name".

I can't tell if that's a real service, but if you installed Express Edition you should be able to connect to it with the SID `xe`.